# C++ incrementing a pointer to an array

Tags: c++

```
int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int (*parr)[10] = &arr;

//prints address of arr and the value 1
cout << parr << " " << *parr[0];

//what is this doing?
parr++;

//prints (what looks like the address of arr[1]) and some long number -8589329222
cout << parr << " " << *parr[0];
```

I thought parr++ would increment the address that parr is pointing to so that *parr[0] is now the address of *parr[1]. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're assuming `parr++` increments by one word. It doesn't. It increments by the size of `*parr`, which in thise case is an `int[10]`, so it's incrementing by the size of 10 integers (probably 40 bytes).

Comment: So it's now effectively `arr[10]`, and another `par++` would make it `arr[20]`?

Comment: @corsiKa: It's effectively `&arr[10]`, yeah, and another increment would make it effectively `&arr[20]` (if that were legal, which it technically isn't).

Answer (score 2):

You only need a pointer to the *start* of the array.

```
int* parr = arr; // points to the 0 element
parr++; // poInts to the first element, 1.
```

Comment: Or, to be more explicit, `int* parr = &arr[0];`. The reason why the other form works too is because given the right context, array names will decay to a pointer pointing to the first element of the array. There are several question dealing with this topic on SO.